# How to find per-phase inductance and resistance of an induction motor in MATLAB?

Tags: simulation, induction-motor, matlab

The data provided is just the output in kW, motor speed, and torque. Is it possible to find the per-phase inductance and resistance in MATLAB, assuming the necessary values of other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question: no, generally it's not possible to find the per-phase inductance nor resistance from those specs. What's possible is to look at motors that have similar ratings and frame size and length - they'll be wound similarly.